# Input type range bubble showing value not displaying properly on start

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a problem with displaying value of **input type="range"**. When page loads ,bubble is positioned in left side of input.

[image]

But my goal is to make that bubble always above the slider thumb. Like this.

[image]

I can't figure it out why, but when I click on slider thumb and try to set new value ,problem disappears and bubble is working just fine. This problem occurs only if page is loaded. Does anybody know what can be the problem? Thank you.

Codesandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-tereshkova-ujk45?file=/src/index.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple add it manually at the start with css like:

```
.range-value {
  //other code you write
  left: calc(49.4949% + 0.10101px);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! :) can you please explain why these numbers? 49.4949% + 0.10101px ?

Comment: You can simple replace that by using dev console. if you look dev console when you change value of range you will see value 50 is `calc(49.4949% + 0.10101px)`. you are welcome ;)

Comment: I don't know what just happened,but I've tried to set different min and max values,so it will be legit BMI calculator and it crashed whole app and I don't know why.

Comment: I cant create new thread yet. but I've updated codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-tereshkova-ujk45?file=/src/index.css

Comment: as you can see ,second input type range is not working at all. Numbers are displaying but bubble is not moving at all.. and second problem is with that effect when you are dragging slider-thumb.. This all happened when I've change min and max values.